# DateTimeIndexに時間をセットしたい

Tags: python, pandas

以下の様にタイムゾーンを設定した際、
indexの時間を一律10:00：00にする方法は無いでしょうか？
特に下記のデータには規則性はありません。

```
DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-03', '2000-01-04', '2000-01-05', '2000-01-06',
               '2000-01-07', '2000-01-10', '2000-01-11', '2000-01-12',
               '2000-01-13', '2000-01-14',
               ...
               '2018-12-19', '2018-12-20', '2018-12-21', '2018-12-23',
               '2018-12-24', '2018-12-25', '2018-12-26', '2018-12-27',
               '2018-12-28', '2018-12-30'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='日付', length=4984, freq=None)

data.index = data.index.tz_localize('Asia/Tokyo')

DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-04 00:00:00+09:00', '2000-01-05 00:00:00+09:00',
               '2000-01-06 00:00:00+09:00', '2000-01-07 00:00:00+09:00',
               '2000-01-11 00:00:00+09:00', '2000-01-12 00:00:00+09:00',
               '2000-01-13 00:00:00+09:00', '2000-01-14 00:00:00+09:00',
               '2000-01-17 00:00:00+09:00', '2000-01-18 00:00:00+09:00',
               ...
               '2018-12-14 00:00:00+09:00', '2018-12-17 00:00:00+09:00',
               '2018-12-18 00:00:00+09:00', '2018-12-19 00:00:00+09:00',
               '2018-12-20 00:00:00+09:00', '2018-12-21 00:00:00+09:00',
               '2018-12-25 00:00:00+09:00', '2018-12-26 00:00:00+09:00',
               '2018-12-27 00:00:00+09:00', '2018-12-28 00:00:00+09:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, Asia/Tokyo]', name='Date', length=4664, freq=None)
```

下記にしたい

```
DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-04 10:00:00+09:00', '2000-01-05 10:00:00+09:00',
               '2000-01-06 10:00:00+09:00', '2000-01-07 10:00:00+09:00',
```

Comment: 途中の日付に飛んでいるところがあるようですが、何か規則性がある/既に出来上がっているデータに対して付与したい/連続した日付のIndexを新規に作り出すのでも構わない、といった細かい条件が明確ならば、追記してみてください。

Comment: `data.index`ということは、`DataFrame`の列が既にあって、それらには既にデータが入っている状態で、`index`の内容を編集したい、ということでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3.7.4 と pandas 0.25.0 でやってみました。

既に何かの`DataFrame`の`index`になっている状態ならば、以下の2行で出来るでしょう。

```
data.index = data.index + pd.Timedelta('0 days 10:00:00')
data.index = data.index.tz_localize('Asia/Tokyo')
```

単独の`DatetimeIndex`オブジェクトならば、いったん`DataFrame`にしてから戻す、以下のような処理になるでしょう。

```
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data = data['日付'] + pd.Timedelta('0 days 10:00:00')
data = pd.DatetimeIndex(data)
data = data.tz_localize('Asia/Tokyo')
```